# R: last tick specified in axis() does not show

Tags: r, plot, axis, label

I can't understand why the the last tick mark that I specify in the axis() function does not appear on my axis. I would like there to be both a tick mark and a label for the value 2 on the vertical axis. Here is what I have:

```
boxplot(rg.ratio[1:8], rg.ratio[9:18], rg.ratio[19:28], rg.ratio[29:38], rg.ratio, col = "orangered2", pch = 18, boxwex = .8, whisklty = 1, axes= FALSE, varwidth = TRUE)

axis(2, at=seq(1.4,2,.1), labels = seq(1.4,2,.1),las =1)
```

[image]

Comment: set the `ylim` in boxplot

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks!